# Windows 7 snap to edge of monitor (not desktop) on multi-monitor setup

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

In Windows 7 I can drag the title bar of a window to the left or right of the desktop and it snaps to be half the monitor width and its height.  However it won't do this at a monitor edge that isn't the edge of the desktop, i.e., the right edge of the left monitor and the left edge of the right monitor.  Is there a way in Windows 7 to do this?  I'm aware of add-on programs such as WinSplit Revolution, but I was hoping to do this natively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Wikipedia's Feature new to Windows 7 page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_new_to_Windows_7) says

- Windows key + Left snaps the current window to the left edge of the screen.
- Windows key + Right snaps the current window to the right half of the screen.

I tried this on a dual-monitor setup and that works.  However there is a "middle" setting, if you are at the right it will first go to the "restore" size, then the next press will go to he left.  Also these help:

- Windows key + Shift + Left and Windows key + Shift + Right move the current window to the left or right display.
- Windows key + Up maximizes the current window.
- Windows key + Down if current window is maximized, restores it; otherwise minimizes current window.

Comment: +1.  The keyboard shortcuts are the only way to do this on the interior edges of a multi-monitor setup, sadly!